# How to set a limit filesize to the uploading file (different limits on different routes)?

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: 2 * 1024 * 1024, extended: true}));
app.use(fileUpload({limits: { fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024 }}));
```

Not working...

Comment: Try to place `app.use(fileUpload(...))` before `app.use(bodyParser(...))`

Comment: this is for global. How to set this for each route?

Comment: You need to place it at every route then - `app.post('/route1', fileUpload(...));`,   `app.post('/route2', fileUpload(...))`